# Proftpd login failure

Tags: linux, debian, sftp, proftpd

I've installed & configured `proftpd` on a remotessh debian server as a non root user following [this guide](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Nonroot.html). I've also created a `AuthUserFile` file using `ftpasswd` util as suggested in the manual. The problem is that i can successfully login to the server locally (using `netkit-ftp`) but when i try to connect from outside i get an error: "Connection denied". I'm running `proftpd` on 20021 port which is opened and not blocked on the remote `proftpd`'d machine (i've check it out using online [open port checker](https://www.ipfingerprints.com/portscan.php)). What can be the reason for remote login faillure?

Comment: How are you FTP'ing to it, and what error are you getting. Does passive vs active mode make a difference? Are you aware that FTP is quite a messy protocol requiring 2 sets of ports?

Comment: I've tried both online web-based clients and also classic netkit-ftp client on another remote ssh server. Setting passive mode doesn't help.

Comment: Did you connect on port 20021? Again, what happens when you try to connect?